# Thymeleaf ModelAttribute List

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I try to have something like a List as a ModelAttribute with Thymeleaf, but I do not get it to work. I read this page http://www.bincsoft.com/blog/thymeleaf-and-lists-in-forms/ but my code fails.

here are my files:

**container class**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;


public class WagerateForm {

    @Valid
    private List<WagerateUi> wagerateuilist;

    public WagerateForm() {
        wagerateuilist = new ArrayList<WagerateUi>();
    }

    public WagerateForm(List<WagerateUi> wagerateuilist) {
        this.wagerateuilist = wagerateuilist;
    }

    //getter , setter omitted
}
```

**my DTO for ui**

```
public class WagerateUi {

    //getter , setter omitted

    private boolean standard;
    private Long value;
}
```

**controller**

```
@Named
@RequestMapping("/wagerate")
public class WagerateController {

@RequestMapping(value="")
public String wagerate(@ModelAttribute("wagerateform") WagerateForm wagerateForm,
        BindingResult bindingResult) {

    List<WagerateUi> wagerateUiList = wagerateForm.getWagerateuilist();

    System.out.println(wagerateUiList.size());

    //dummy items
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        WagerateUi temp = new WagerateUi();
        temp.setValue(100L);
        wagerateUiList.add(temp);
    }


    return "wagerate";
}
```

**thymeleaf html**

```
<form id="wagerateform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="#" th:object="${wagerateform}" th:action="@{/wagerate}" method="post">              

    <div th:each="wagerateui, iterStat  : ${wagerateform.wagerateuilist}">      
        <input th:field="*{wagerateform[__${iterStat.index}__].value}" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Test</button>

</form>
```

**error message**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'wagerateform[0]' of bean class [WagerateForm]: Bean property 'wagerateform[0]' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getNestedBeanWrapper(BeanWrapperImpl.java:571)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getBeanWrapperForPropertyPath(BeanWrapperImpl.java:548)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:714)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractPropertyBindingResult.getActualFieldValue(AbstractPropertyBindingResult.java:99)
    at org.springframework.validation.AbstractBindingResult.getFieldValue(AbstractBindingResult.java:229)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:120)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:348)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:288)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:260)
```

The size of the list in the controller is always 0. I cant see whats wrong, i tried different ways, but I think my Thymeleaf/Spring EL is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working so far with:

```
<input th:value="${wagerateform.wagerateuilist[__${iterStat.index}__].value}" class="form-control">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `wagerateform` is not a List, the List is the `wagerateuilist`. With the `th:each` you fill the `wagerateui` object with elements while your looping through your List.

```
<div th:each="wagerateui : ${wagerateform.wagerateuilist}">      
        <input th:field="${wagerateui.value}" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: yes you are right, it is not a list, your code does not work in my case i get an error with bindingresult. Its now working with :<input th:value="${wagerateform.wagerateuilist[__${iterStat.index}__].value}" class="form-control">
. Thanks

Comment: I removed the comma in `wagerateui, : ${wagerateform.wagerateuilist}`, I think it should work now.